# In Django how to display data from current user that's logged in

Tags: python, django

here am looking for the particular data of logged in user to display in their profile
i dont know how to do that please help me with some hint 
am new here building a django project

this is models.py

```
class Loader_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Loader")
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sending_item = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image_of_load = models.ImageField(default='',upload_to='static/img')
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    metric_unit = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='SOME STRING')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pick_up_time = models.DateField()
    drop_time = models.DateField()
    paid_by = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("Loader:post", kwargs={ "username": self.user.username,"pk": self.pk})
```

this is view.py

```
class Loader_post_list(ListView,SelectRelatedMixin):
    context_object_name = 'Loader'
    model = Loader_post
    template_name = "my_job.html"
    select_related = ("user")
```

so here is my question that how can i display the data of that loggedin user in their profile
after posting the post the data directly display in their profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it as follows

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Loader_post.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return qs
```